# Postgres JSONB SELECT Query with combined condition for a json array

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

Using PostgreSQL 14 I have a table 'fruits' with a JSONB column named 'items' containing this sample data:

```
[{"anz": 4, "typ": "Banana"}, {"anz": 5, "typ": "Apple"}, {"anz": 2, "typ": "Grapefruit"}]
[{"anz": 1, "typ": "Banana"}, {"anz": 1, "typ": "Apple"}, {"anz": 3, "typ": "Grapefruit"}]
```

this works:

```
SELECT * FROM fruits WHERE items @> '[{"typ":"Apple"}]';
SELECT * FROM fruits WHERE (items -> 0 ->> 'lvl')::int > 4;
```

Bu now I would like to fetch only the record where Apple has 'anz > 3'. Combining the WHERE clauses from the queries above doesn't fit of course. What's the appropriate SQL?

Expected Output should be the identified record (SELECT * FROM .. WHERE ..)

Comment: Could you edit your question and add the expected output ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to extract the array into elements by using `json_array_elements()` then apply your conditions:

```
SELECT i.value as item
FROM fruits f
CROSS JOIN jsonb_array_elements(items) i
WHERE f.items @> '[{"typ":"Apple"}]'
      AND (i->>'anz')::int > 3
      AND i->>'typ' = 'Apple';
```

Results :

```
item
{"anz": 5, "typ": "Apple"}
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/-TDBG0Ys)

Comment: Notice that with the `CROSS JOIN`, a record might be output multiple times if the `items` contain multiple apples that match the condition. If you don't want that, use a subquery with `WHERE EXISTS(SELECT * FROM jsonb_array_elements(items) i WHERE …)`, or go with Zegarek's jsonpath approach.

Comment: Thumbs up for tossing in the `@>` first, thanks to which this is [able to lean on a default `gin(items)` index](https://dbfiddle.uk/sQug-2eU)

Answer (score 2):

You're using `jsonb`, so you have the full support of [`JSONPath`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-SQLJSON-PATH-OPERATORS) expressions: [demo at db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/JRC6Ij-O)

```
select * from fruits where items @? '$[*] ? (@.typ=="Apple" && @.anz>3)';
```

| id | items |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | [{"anz": 4, "typ": "Banana"}, {"anz": 5, "typ": "Apple"}, {"anz": 2, "typ": "Grapefruit"}] |

- [`@?` operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSONB-OP-TABLE) checks if the `jsonb` returns anything for the jsonpath expression
- `$` is your top-level thing
- `[*]` checks all elements of the array
- `?` is a filter, like a `where`
- `@` is the element considered by the filter
- `&&` is the logical `AND` operator

You can speed this up by adding [an index](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createindex.html):

```sql
create index on fruits using gin(items jsonb_path_ops);
```

[The doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-json.html#JSON-INDEXING) isn't immediately clear on whether your expression should be able to use it:

> For these operators, a GIN index extracts clauses of the form `accessors_chain = constant` out of the `jsonpath` pattern, and does the index search based on the keys and values mentioned in these clauses. The accessors chain may include `.key`, `[*]`, and `[index]` accessors. The `jsonb_ops` operator class also supports `.*` and `.**` accessors, but the `jsonb_path_ops` operator class does not.

But [it does](https://dbfiddle.uk/JRC6Ij-O).

Comment: Works [since PostgreSQL 12](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/release/12.0/#id-1.11.6.23.5.7).

Comment: perfect, works as wanted, thx!

Comment: btw: this would be the appropriate index for this type of query?
CREATE INDEX idx_typ_anz ON fruits USING GIN ((items -> 'typ'), (items -> 'anz'));

Comment: A generic `gin(items jsonb_path_ops)` would be closer but I don't think this particular one will be supported by an index - that heavily depends on the jsonpath expression complexity. Simple path with wildcards and equality will use it, but this combination of `>` and `==` might not. If that jsonb structure is stable and you mostly query it that way, you're on the right path with the expressions: you could extract the expressions to generated columns and index those. That would also let you use a simple `where`. If you think about it, it'd be better mostly because it'd be normalisation

Comment: @Rainer you're in luck, turns out it's [more than happy to use the generic GIN index above](https://dbfiddle.uk/JRC6Ij-O).